# JavaScript returning 'undefined' when calling prototype member

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype

So I'm new to OOP in JavaScript and having trouble understanding why I'm getting 'undefined' in the following code, please help:

```js
function Vehicle(energyType, energy) {
 this.energyType = energyType;
 this.energy = energy;
}

function Car(energyType, energy) {
 Vehicle.call(energyType, energy);

 this.doors = 4;
}

Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype);

Vehicle.prototype.run = function() {
 console.log(`This vehicle is running on ${this.energyType}.`);
}

const c = new Car('gas', 80);

c.run();
```

When you run the code it says "This vehicle is running on undefined" even though I said Car had gas energyType...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `.call`, the first argument should be the `this` you want the called function to refer to. So,

```
Vehicle.call(energyType, energy);
```

results in `Vehicle` being called with *one* parameter, with the `this` value being what was initially the `energyType` variable (coerced into an object, because `this` has to be an object, not a primitive). You can see this if you `console.log` inside `Vehicle`:

```js
function Vehicle(energyType, energy) {
  console.log('this', this);
  console.log('energyType', energyType);
  console.log('energy', energy);
 this.energyType = energyType;
 this.energy = energy;
}

function Car(energyType, energy) {
 Vehicle.call(energyType, energy);

 this.doors = 4;
}

Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype);

Vehicle.prototype.run = function() {
 console.log(`This vehicle is running on ${this.energyType}.`);
}

const c = new Car('gas', 80);

c.run();
```

Change to:

```
Vehicle.call(this, energyType, energy);
```

```js
function Vehicle(energyType, energy) {
 this.energyType = energyType;
 this.energy = energy;
}

function Car(energyType, energy) {
 Vehicle.call(this, energyType, energy);

 this.doors = 4;
}

Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype);

Vehicle.prototype.run = function() {
 console.log(`This vehicle is running on ${this.energyType}.`);
}

const c = new Car('gas', 80);

c.run();
```

Comment: lol.. funny how a simply typo can take you 30 minutes to figure out sometimes xD. THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

It's missing a `this`.

```
Vehicle.call(this, energyType, energy);
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

> function.call(thisArg, arg1, arg2, ...)

Pass `this` in  `Vehicle.call(this,energyType, energy);`

```js
function Vehicle(energyType, energy) {
 this.energyType = energyType;
 this.energy = energy;
}

function Car(energyType, energy) {
 Vehicle.call(this,energyType, energy);

 this.doors = 4;
}

Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype);

Vehicle.prototype.run = function() {
 console.log(`This vehicle is running on ${this.energyType}.`);
}

const c = new Car('gas', 80);

c.run();
```